# Derivatives of infimum in variational problem

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, calculus-of-variations

Define
$$
F(\lambda,x):=g(x)+\lambda\int\limits_{\partial_e Y} f(y) \, d\mu_x(y)
$$
where

- $Y$ is a convex space and $w^*$-compact, moreover $Y$ forms a Bauer simplex (in particular $Y$ corresponds to some subset of some algebraic state space),
- its extreme boundary $\partial_e Y$ is $w^*$-compact,
- the points $x$ correspond to elements in $Y$,
- the measures $\mu_x$ are probability measures (depending on $x$) and have support in $\partial_e Y$,
- $g$ is a functional ($w^*$-continuous and affine) on $Y$,
- $f$ is a continuous function on $\partial_e Y$,
- $\lambda$ is a real parameter,
- $F(0,\cdot)$ is assumed to be a $w^*$-continuous, affine functional on $Y$.

Then I consider
$$
R(\lambda):=\inf_{x\in Y} F(\lambda,x),
$$ which can be shown to exist.

I am interested in computing the derivative of $R$ with respect to $\lambda$. For this, one clearly needs some smoothness of $\inf$.

**My question is**: under what precise conditions this derivative can be taken, and moreover which result will it produce? For example, given that $R$ is differentiable in $\lambda$ and that the set of minimizers corresponding to $R(0)$ (i.e. the points $x\in Y$ for which $R(0)=F(0,x)$) is nonempty, what can we say?

I thank you in advance!

Comment: I believe the continuous version of your question is important. Please see MO question 394085 and Martin Hairer's response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $t:=\lambda$, so that
$$R(t):=\inf_{x\in Y}F(t,x).$$
Suppose that $\int_{\partial_e Y}f\,d\mu_x$ is lower-semicontinuous in $x$ (with respect to the appropriate topology, which you appear to assume to be the $w^*$-topology with respect to some unspecified duality). Then the set
$$Y_t:=\{x\in Y\colon F(t,x)=R(t)\}$$
is a nonempty compact set, for each real $t$. Further, let
$$L_t:=\Big\{\int_{\partial_e Y}f\,d\mu_x\colon x\in Y_t\Big\}.$$

Take now any real $t$.
If $L_t$ is a singleton set $\{l_t\}$, then $R$ is differentiable at $t$ and $R'(t)=l_t$.
If $L_t$ is not a singleton set, then $R$ is not differentiable at $t$.

These statements follow e.g. from Theorems 0.25 and 1.5 in the book by Levin "Convex analysis in spaces of measurable functions and its applications in mathematics and economics", Moscow: Nauka, 1985. (I have this book only in Russian.)

Comment: This is a nice answer, thank you very much. Unfortunately, I cannot read Russian, but perhaps such results are known in other literature as well.  To be honest I expected differentiability of the function R(t) also in the case that L_t did not consist of a singleton, where then a certain convex combination of measures (depending in particular on g) \mu_x  would be selected.  This is  thus impossible.  One more thing, the set Y_t defined above is convex?

Comment: @Kris : I am pretty sure such results have been published elsewhere. The singleton-nonsingleton dilemma and how it affects the differentiability can be clearly seen in this toy example: $g(t):=\inf_{x\in Y}g_x(t)$ for real $t$, where $g_x(t):=xt$ and $Y$ is either $\{-1,1\}$ or  $[-1,1]$, so that $g(t)=-|t|$, $g$ is not differentiable at $0$, and $Y_0=Y$. So, here $Y_0$ does not have to be convex. In your setting, $Y_t$ does not have to be convex either, especially given that you do not specify the dependence of $\mu_x$ on $x$.

Comment: this is very clear. For my purpose I am particularly interested in Y_0 which corresponds to the set of minimizers of the functional g corresponding to a certain 'free energy' (a thermodynamic functional) which can be shown to be a convex set, but this does not hold automatically, as you have pointed out.